# PHP using a variable in a file download

Tags: php, file, download

I have a variable generated by a command that is ran. Everything seems to work fine and I get a file download dialog with the correct filesize. Issue is I am unable to get my varible to be the actual filename. It is always $fullpath as my filename

I am have tried many different ways including without quotes

```
 header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$fullpath"');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$fullpath"));

    $fp = fopen("$fullpath", "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't parse variables in single quotes `'`.  Use double quotes `"` but you also need to escape any double quotes you want as part of the string by using `\"`.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fullpath\"");
```

or concat the variable and the string.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fullpath . '"');
```

Also, adding quotes in these places serves no purpose:

```
filesize($fullpath);
fopen($fullpath);
```